# Use of Crosswalk for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

As you know, the amazing Crosswalk project provides us with a up-to-date Chromium browser and rendering engine as to allow us to write our Cordova apps simply to the latest version of Web APIs that Chrome supports. This obviously is good and well on Android, and since Apple forces the Safari engine on iOS, I reckoned there would be no Crosswalk for iOS. But apparently, Crosswalk even provides a [Crosswalk for iOS](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/ios.html). Yet, it says clearly that though they are Crosswalk, they still use Apple's `WKWebView`. So I don't get it. What is the use of Crosswalk for iOS versus just using Cordova?

Answer (score 2):

I might have misunderstood your questions, but the answer to it (What is the use of Crosswalk for iOS versus just using Cordova?) is literally on the first page of the link you posted:

- **Extended WKWebView**

  The Crosswalk Project for iOS is built on top of WKWebView, the modern WebKit framework that debuted in iOS 8. We extend the WKWebView with the Crosswalk extension framework. For detailed information, refer to Embedding Mode & Native APIs.
- Crosswalk Extension Framework

  Extensions allow you to extend the ability of the Crosswalk runtime. You create your feature using Swift or Objective-C and expose it as a JavaScript function or object. The JavaScript stub code can be generated automatically based on the native interface. For more information, refer to Extensions.
- Cordova Plugins Support

  To leverage existing Cordova plugins, a Cordova extension is provided to simulate the Cordova environment. Simply place the source files of the Cordova plugins into your project and register the plugin classes in the manifest. For more information, refer to Cordova plugin support.

Comment: Hi, isn't all of this just the same even if you just use Cordova? You can use the iOS webview, you can write plugins to use native code, and you can obviously use Cordova plugins? Please correct me if I'm wrong tho

Comment: You are absolutely right. You don't have to use Crosswalk with Cordova, you can just use built in iOS webview. For me, the big advantage of using Crosswalk is for developing the same app for both Android and iOS, when Crosswalk is helping with differences in their web views as they have different rendering engine.

Comment: So youre saying that Crosswalk changes the rendering of the Webview? Ah, that makes more sense I guess